# Why is my component not rendering even though there is no error?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a music slider component but I cant figure out why it's not working. It was working previously but I can't recall when it broke.

Maybe it's something small that I'm missing but I can't figure out what that is.
Also, it's showing in the components section in dev tools.

I have simplified the code a little but to make the example more clear.
Thanks!

```js
import SongSlider from '../components/SongSlider';

const songs = [
  
  {
    artist: 'Drake',
    songName: 'One Dance',
    poster: Drake,
    songFile: DrakeOneDance
  },
  {
    artist: 'Adelle',
    songName: 'Hello',
    poster: Adelle,
    songFile: AdelleHello
  },
  {
    artist: 'Juice Wrld',
    songName: 'Lucid Dreams',
    poster: JuiceWrld,
    songFile: JuiceWrldLucidDreams
  },
  {
    artist: 'Kings of Leon',
    songName: 'Pyro',
    poster: KingsOfLeon,
    songFile: KingsOfLeonPyro
  },
  {
    artist: 'Brittney Spears',
    songName: 'Toxic',
    poster: BrittneySpears,
    songFile: BrittneySpearsToxic
  },
  {
    artist: 'Weeknd',
    songName: 'Starboy',
    poster: Weeknd,
    songFile: WeekndStarboy
  },
  {
    artist: 'Lil Mosey',
    songName: 'Noticed',
    poster: LilMosey,
    songFile: LilMoseyNoticed
  },
  {
    artist: 'Chainsmokers',
    songName: 'Just like this',
    poster: ChainSmokers,
    songFile: ChainSmokersSomething
  },
  {
    artist: 'RHCP',
    songName: 'Under The Bridge',
    poster: RedHotChilliPeppers,
    songFile: RhcpUnderTheBridge
  },
  {
    artist: 'Taylor Swift',
    songName: 'Lover',
    poster: TaylorSwift,
    songFile: TaylorSwiftLover
  },
  {
    artist: 'Elvis',
    songName: 'Return To Sender',
    poster: Elvis,
    songFile: ElvisReturnToSender
  }

]


function Music() {


    return (

      <div className='music-container'>
          <SongSlider songs={songs} />
      </div>
     
    );
  }

  export default Music
```

```js
import '../css/SongSlider.css'

function SongSlider({songs}) {
    
(
    <>

    <div className="media-scrollers snaps-inline">
        
        {songs.map((song) => (    

            <div className='main-container'>
                <div className="media-element">
                    <img src={song.poster} />
                </div>

                <div className="details">
                     <h4>{song.artist}</h4>
                    <p>{song.songName}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    
    
    </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default SongSlider
```

Comment: Typo?  Your `SongSlider` component doesn't *return* anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything.
Looks like you are mixing syntaxes. Return without body works with arrow function expressions not function declarations.

```
function SongSlider({songs}) {
    
return (
    <>

    <div className="media-scrollers snaps-inline">
        
        {songs.map((song) => (    

            <div className='main-container'>
                <div className="media-element">
                    <img src={song.poster} />
                </div>

                <div className="details">
                     <h4>{song.artist}</h4>
                    <p>{song.songName}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    
    
    </div>

    </>
  )
}
```

Or use

```
const SongSlider = ({songs}) => ({
   //No need for return 
    <>
   .... 
    </>
});`
```

Comment: Ah yes. I somehow didn't notice the typo. Thanks!